# Changing const member within class

Tags: c++, initialization, constants, subclass

I would like to let a `const int` be changed by a function within a class.

```cpp
class Parent 
{
int currentIndex; 
private: 
    initMember(const int& member) 
    {
        member = currentIndex++;
    }

}


class Child 
{
const int Member1;
const int Member2;

    Child () 
    {
        initMember(Member1);
        initMember(Member2);
    }



}
```

Who ever writes the subclass should only declare `const int`'s for indexing. The actuall value should be managed by `Parent` since this class uses the value to address stuff in arrays and so on. So the goal is to let the writer of the subclass declare, but not change (at least not easily) `Member1` and `Member2`.

What would be the best way to do this?

Comment: That makes no sense, you say something is constant so you *can't* change it.

Comment: In your code `initMember(const int member)` copies `member` so actual value passed in (`Member1` and `Member2`) will not be changed by assignment inside `initMember`. Did you mean `initMember(const int &member)`?

Comment: You can't make changes to a const

Comment: constant can't be changed, that's why they are called constants.

Comment: Ok, so what would be a solution for my problem?
The idea is to let the parent class handle the const member value. 
I want to delay the initialization, after initMember, the values don't have to change. And yes, the code above doesn't work, the question was if something similar could be implemented instead.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You probably are looking for a way to initialize const members upon creation, using a data member in a parent class:

```
class Parent 
{
    protected:
    int currentIndex; 
};

class Child : public Parent
{
   const int Member1;
   const int Member2;

    Child () : Member1(currentIndex++), Member2(currentIndex++)
    {
    }
};
```

Comment: That's pretty close to what I had in mind. I've came to a conclusion after reading this post,...

I've added a function `int initMember() {}` to `Parent` which returns the value for the `const int Member1`. It looks a bit odd because the initializer list gets quite long and complex but the result is what I had in mind.

Comment: Much better to use a function because of encapsulation.

Answer (score 1):

Non static const members **must be initialized** in the member initializer list and **cannot** be changed afterwards.
You can try this:

```
class Child
{
private:
    int _currentIndex;
    const int _member1, _member2;
public:
    Child() :
        _currentIndex(0),
        _member1(_currentIndex++),
        _member2(_currentIndex++)
    {
    }
};
```